# How to define an operator on an enumerator?

Tags: c++, enumeration

I have an enumerator

```
enum oper {PLUS, MINUS, TIMES, DIVIDE, EXP};
```

which I am using to construct a tree out of mathematical functions. In the way I've defined the `enum` is in ascending order of precedence. So I want to be able to do things like this:

```
oper op1 = PLUS; 
oper op2 = DIVIDE; 
std::cout << (op1 < op2); // should print out "1"
```

If this possible, and if so, how do I construct the function that defines the operator?

I know this is basic `C++` stuff. I need to job my memory hehe. ;)

Comment: well, this works out of the box ([proof](http://ideone.com/IbXRCO)).

Comment: You should know that, given that you originated the language ;) Seriously, you need C++11 `enum class oper {...}`, then just define `operator<` for `oper` values.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: I presume the OP wants to solve the problem even when you have to add operator `OR` later on, which isn't higher priority than `DIVIDE`, for example.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Does that work in C++98? I don't use C++11.

Comment: @MatsPetersson and what would the expected result be in that case? why couldn't he just add it where it belongs?

Comment: @BjarneStroustrop It does, I'm just used to sticking with C++11 whenever possible, but this does work in C++98 too.

Comment: Perhaps, because it will break binary compatibility somewhere?

Comment: But if re-ordering doesn't cause any problem then just comparing is fine.

Comment: @MatsPetersson you don't really need to create a a class for this, do you ?  You could just overload `bool operator<(oper a, oper b)`

Comment: @MatsPetersson Oh, I see, indeed. (but since in C++, almost everything in headers is part of the ABI, and you almost always need to recompile on header change anyway, this might not be a problem. All depending on the actual situation, though.)

Comment: @Christophe: No, not a class `enum class`, which is a C++11 construct which defines enums with a "stricter type" than regular `enum`. A regular `enum` is simply a set of constant integer values, and you can do `enum X { A, B }; enum Y { C, D }; void func(Y y) {...}; func(A);` and the compiler will happily compile that without any objection.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, Not quite. `int` to `enum` is not implicit like the other way is. However, `enum` to `int` is a standard conversion, so you could, for example, make `func` take a class with an implicit conversion constructor from `int` and it would compile given `A`.

Comment: Ah, and you don't need `enum class` to declare an `operator`. There are some other cases when `enum class` is beneficial, but this seems to not be one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with re-ordering when you introduce new operators e.g. `AND`, `OR`, `NOT`, etc, then you can just make sure you order your operators from lowest to highest, and the standard `operator<` is fine.

If you still want a custom operator, e.g. because you need to be able to add more operators and still maintain binary compatibility with other modules or some such, then doing something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

enum oper { PLUS, MINUS, TIMES, DIVIDE, EXP, MAX_OPER };

bool operator<(oper a, oper b)
{
    int pri[MAX_OPER] = { 5, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    return pri[a] < pri[b];
}


int main()
{
    oper op1 = PLUSS; 
    oper op2 = DIVIDES; 
    std::cout << (op1 < op2);
}
```

will work (note that this particular example will make the output 0, since I rearranged the `pri` table just to show that it DOES something other than the default `operator<` for enums).

I prefer simply make it more obvious what you are doing by making a function like this:

```
bool isSecondOperHigher(oper left, oper right)
{
   bool result;
   ... do some stuff to come up with result here ... 
   return result; 
}
```

(It is not always obvious that `operator<` for an `enum oper` is giving back true for which has lower priority)